# Transparent borders are adding to width x height

Tags: html

Borders are supposed to go outside of the width x height of a div. But this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/L33cK/5/ - shows borders being *added* to the width x height of a div when they're transparent. I would expect the line in the jsfiddle to be 1px when given transparent 1px borders, but it's 3px.

Does anyone understand what's going on here?  I'm looking at it with Chrome.

Thanks

```
div#line {
    margin-left:100px;
    width:1px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    border:1px solid transparent;

}
```

Comment: Well, it works if you remove `solid`

Comment: @Amber the default border style (if you don't provide one) is `none`, that means, no border.

Comment: @MrLister True, but from the description, the OP either wants that, or your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The borders are transparent, so you can see the div's background through them. It's that simple.

In [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L33cK/6/) I've added another div that has a dotted border.

```css
background:red; border:10px dotted yellow
```

And you can see the background of the div between the dots of the border.

So if you want the borders to be the colour of the body background, the solution is to not make them transparent, but to give them the same background-color as the body. Or, use margins rather than borders.

Since the div is in *content-box* mode(*), the CSS `width` property does not designate the total outer width of the div, but its content area. The outer width is equal to `width` plus the size of the padding plus the size of the border. (If you give the div some padding as well, you will see that the outer width gets even larger, even if the `width` property remains 1px.)

(*) You can change this behaviour by using the `box-sizing` property. See [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) on how to use it and what vendor prefixes to apply. Basically, with `box-sizing: border-box` you tell the browser that `width` is to be taken as the outer width of the element rather than the content area.

Comment: "The borders are transparent, so you can see the div's background through them. It's that simple."  But the div is only 1px wide so there shouldn't be any div to see behind the transparent borders.

Comment: You say the div is 1px wide, but in reality, it's the CSS `width` property that is 1px. In this case, equal to the _content area_ of the div. I'll update the answer.